# The code is showing error : "Default2.Conv.Conv(double) is inaccessible due to its protection level"

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code that keeps showing this error. I am now very clueless.

This was working when I tried it at college but when I tried at home it was showing something different.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double a = Double.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
        Conv obj = new Conv(a);
        obj.rtd();
        Label1.Text = "Rupees to Dollar : " + Convert.ToString(obj.d);
        obj.dtr();
        Label2.Text = "Dollar to Rupees : " + Convert.ToString(obj.r);
        obj.rte();
        Label3.Text = "Rupees to Dollar : " + Convert.ToString(obj.e);
        obj.etr();
        Label4.Text = "Rupees to Dollar : " + Convert.ToString(obj.r);

    }

    public class Conv
    {
        public double r, e, a, d;
        Conv(double amount)
        {
            a = amount;
        }

        public void rtd()
        {
            d = a / 68.96;
        }

        public void dtr()
        {
            r = a * 68.96;
        }

        public void rte()   
        {
            d = a / 77.35;
        }

        public void etr()
        {
            d = a * 77.35;
        }
    }
}
```

I am also new to ASP so I really need to understand this problem.

I really need some help with this.

I expected it to work but this single error is holding me back.

Comment: trying adding `public` in front of `Conv(double amount)`

Comment: The code's working now. Can you please give me an explanation

Comment: You have access to the internet. Try researching the explanation for yourself.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers